# How to pass total from checkout page to payment page

Tags: javascript, html

So I somehow made function that it pass values from product page to specific div in checkout page,now I will need that it pass total from checkout to payment page

So this is my product page:

```
          
      <header>
        <!--Nav-->
        <div class="nav container">
          <a href="">Deni Beatz</a>
          <!--Cart Icon-->
          <i class="bx bx-shopping-bag" id="cart-icon"></i>
          <div class="notification" id="cart-notification">0</div>
          <!--Cart-->
          <div class="cart">
            <h2 class="cart-title">Your Cart</h2>
            <!--Content-->
            <div class="cart-content">
              <div class="cart-content">
                
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Total-->
            <div class="total">
              <div class="total-title">Total</div>
              <div class="total-price" id="total-price total">$0</div>
            </div>
            <!--Buy Button-->
            <form action="checkout.html">
            <button type="button" class="btn-buy">Continue to purchase</button>
            </form>
            <!--Cart Close-->
            <i class="bx bx-x" id="close-cart"></i>
            <!-- Continue to purchase button moved here -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>

          <section id="prodetails" class="section-p1">
            <div class="productcontainer" id="enjoy">
                <div class="single-pro-image">
                  <img src="../data/high.png"  width="100%" id="product-image" class="product-img">
                </div>
            
                <div class="single-pro-details" action="C:\s\starter-ruby\client\checkout.html">
                  <h4 class="product-title" id="title">Enjoy</h4>
                  <h2 id="price" class="price">$20</h2>
                  <h3>Select Licence</h3>
                  <select id="select" class="licence">
                    <option>MP3</option>
                    <option>Tagged Wav</option>
                    <option>Un-Tagged Wav</option>
                    <option>Stems</option>
                    <option>Exlusive</option>
                  </select>
    
                    <script>
                      let select = document.getElementById('select');
                      let price = document.getElementById('price');
    
                      // Prices
                      let prices = {
                        "MP3": '$20',
                        "Tagged Wav": '$27',
                        "Un-Tagged Wav": '$30',
                        "Stems": '$120',
                        "Exlusive": '$300'
                      }
    
                      // When the value of select changes, this event listener fires and changes the text content of price to the coresponding value from the prices object
                      select.addEventListener('change', () => {
                        price.textContent = prices[select.value];
                      });
                    </script>
                    <button class="add-cart">Add To Cart <i class='bx bx-cart-add add-cart'></i></button>
                    <h4>Product Details</h4>
                    <span>Lil Tjay x Trap Type Beat - "Enjoy" in key D# Minor and 160 BPM,It has vibe of Lil Tjay , Pop Smoke and more , Prices are great for this type of beat;Tagged Mastered MP3 for $25,$27 for Tagged Unmastered Wav,$30 for Untagged unmastered Wav,$70 for Stems and $120 for Exlusive</span>
                </div>
                <div id="audio">
                    <audio controls style="width:100%;" id="audio-clip">
                        <source src="Audio/Enjoy 160 x D sharp minor.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
              </section> 

              <script>
                var selectedItems = [];
  const addToCartButton = document.querySelector('.add-cart');

  if (addToCartButton) {
    addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const productTitle = document.querySelector('#title').textContent;
      const productPrice = document.querySelector('#price').textContent;
      const selectedLicense = document.querySelector('#select').value;
      const productImage = document.getElementById('product-image');
      const ImageSrc = productImage.src;
      const audioElement = document.getElementById('audio-clip');
      const audioSrc = audioElement.src;

      const cartItem = {
        title: productTitle,
        price: productPrice,
        license: selectedLicense,
        image: ImageSrc,
        audio: audioSrc
      };

      let selectedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems')) || [];

      // Check if the item already exists in the cart
      let existingItemIndex = selectedItems.findIndex(item => item.title === productTitle && item.license === selectedLicense);

      if (existingItemIndex > -1) {
        // If the item already exists, update the license
        selectedItems[existingItemIndex].license = selectedLicense;
      } else {
        // If the item doesn't exist, add it to the cart
        selectedItems.push(cartItem);
      }

      console.log(selectedItems);

      localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(selectedItems));
    });
  }
</script>
```

and this is my page which display products details in specific div

```
  <h2 style="text-align:center;">Checkout</h2>
  <div id="product-items">
    <p style="text-align:center;"><span id="added-products"></p>
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="cart-items"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="clear-button">CLEAR ITEMS - REDIRECT TO HOME</button>
<script>
  document.getElementById("clear-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = ""; // clear the HTML content of the cart-items div
  const subtotalSpan = document.getElementById("subtotal");
  const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total");
  subtotalSpan.innerHTML = "";
  totalSpan.innerHTML = "$0"; // set the total price to $0
  
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedItems"); // remove the selected items from localStorage
  clearCartItems();
});
</script>
  <!--fix the error that how much items in one cart is,e.g if add 2 mp3 and that it does not display that both 2 items
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cartProducts.length; i++) {
        if (cartProducts[i].title === title && cartProducts[i].option === licence) {
            alert('You have already added this product to your cart with the same option.');
            return;
        }
    }
  -->
  </div>

  <div class="total">
    <h3 style="text-align:center; display: none;">Subtotal: <br><span id="subtotal"></span></h3>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Total: <br><span id="total">$0</span></h3>
    <form action="payment.html">
      <button type="submit" class="buy-btn" style="background-color: rgb(29, 4, 216);">Continue to purchase</button>
    </form>
    <a href="index.html" onclick="alert('You will be redirected to the home page')"><button style="background-color: rgb(216, 4, 4);">Cancel</button></a>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    const totalAmount = 100; // Replace this with your actual total amount
    const totalElement = document.getElementById("total");
    totalElement.innerHTML = `Total: $${(totalAmount / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
  
    const checkoutForm = document.querySelector('form[action="payment.html"]');
    checkoutForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const queryString = new URLSearchParams({
        total: totalAmount
      });
      const url = `payment.html?${queryString}`;
      window.location.href = url;
    });
  </script>
  <!--It does clear but wonder , make that you cant click on button if that function is done-->
</body>
<script>
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  const storedCartItem = localStorage.getItem("selectedItems");  
  let subtotal = 0;

  const continueButton = document.getElementById("buy-btn");
  const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear-button");

  function clearCartItems() {
  // Clear the HTML content of the cart-items div
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = "";

  // Set the subtotal and total to $0
  const subtotalSpan = document.getElementById("subtotal");
  const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total");
  subtotalSpan.innerHTML = "";
  totalSpan.innerHTML = "$0";

  // Remove the selected items from localStorage
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedItems");

  alert("Added items will be cleared.");
  // Change the URL to the index page and prevent going to the checkout page
  window.location.href = "sproduct6.html";
  history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.href);

  // Update the UI
  document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
  document.getElementById("buy-btn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("clear-button").style.display = "none";

   if (cartItemCount == 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You have no items in your cart. Let's get back to product page.");
      window.location.href = ('sproduct6.html');
    }, 50); // 3 second delay 
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
    continueButton.style.display = "none";
    clearButton.style.display = "none";
    // Save the visibility state of the buttons
    localStorage.setItem("buttonsVisible", "false");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "YOU ADDED THIS PRODUCTS";
  } 
}

if (storedCartItem) {
  const cartItem = JSON.parse(storedCartItem); // Parse the storedCartItem string into an array

  for (let i = 0; i < cartItem.length; i++) {
    const cartItemElement = document.createElement("div");  

    
    cartItemElement.innerHTML = `
        <hr />
        <h3>${cartItem[i].title}</h3>  
        <p>Price: ${cartItem[i].price}</p>
        <p>License: ${cartItem[i].license}</p>
        <img src="${cartItem[i].image}" width='30%'/><br>
        <audio controls style="width:50%;">
          <source src="${cartItem[i].audio}" type="audio/mp3"> 
        </audio>
        `;
    // ADD DELETE OPTION 

    cartItemsDiv.appendChild(cartItemElement);

    const price = Number(cartItem[i].price.replace("$", "")); // Parse price as a number and remove dollar sign
    subtotal += price;
    // MAKE REPLACE TITLE TO YOU HAVE NO ITEMS IN YOUR CART
  }

  const subtotalElement = document.querySelector("#subtotal");
  subtotalElement.textContent = `$${subtotal.toFixed(2)}`;

  const totalElement = document.querySelector("#total");
  const total = subtotal;
  totalElement.textContent = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
  const totalPriceInput = document.querySelector("#total_price");
  totalPriceInput.value = total.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
</html>
```

and this is page where I want total of checkout to appear with no hardcoding it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stripe Sample</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A demo of Stripe" />

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="./payment.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sr-root">
      <span id="total"></span>
      <div class="sr-main">
        <h1>Pay with a bunch of payment option</h1>

        <form id="payment-form" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    
          <div id="payment-element"></div>
    
          <button>Pay</button><!--Make functional-->
          <!--Make total price hidden and that total of this is same as in checkout and that its connected to ruby-->
          <div id="error-messages"></div>
        </form>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like what you're using to pass values from one page to another is `localStorage`. It's a storage space, like a very small DB or a spreadsheet, where any page belonging to the same domain can access the same data. So localhost/index.html, localhost/cart.html and localhost/checkout.html will be able to access the same data. The method you used to set a value in the localStorage was this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem. And you used the getItem method to retrieve values. So I suggest you do the same from cart to checkout page.